# what to use to get data from the gridpanel?

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

What is the difference between itemdblclick and rowdblclick?  Both of these methods seem to work well for gridpanel. Which is preferable for getting data from a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention itemdblclick this seems to be the classic framework.

```
itemdblclick ( grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) 
rowdblclick ( grid, record, element, rowIndex, e, eOpts )
```

`itemdblclick` and `rowdblclick` are fired from different sources, but otherwise both are equally good to use. For both you receive the `record`, which holds the data and you receive an index, if you need it.

For me it is more about, what you want to tell another programmer, what you are listening for. And that's where you can differ between `cell` and `row`.

The record will be the same for both.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Now I get it